# Difference of convex functions with many oscillations (looking for examples)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

It is known [(see e.g. here [pdf])](https://msp.org/pjm/1959/9-3/pjm-v9-n3-p.pdf#page=81) that any function $f: \mathbb{R} -> \mathbb{R}$ with locally bounded left- and right derivatives can be represented as a *difference of convex functions*. Consequently, there must exist convex functions $f$ and $g$, such that the difference $h = f - g$ is (perhaps counter-intuitively) a highly oscillating function with arbitrary many local maxima and minima. My question is: **Are there any nice explicit examples of functions $f, g$ and $h = f-g$ with these properties?**

Comment: Something like $\sin(nx)=(\sin(nx)+n^2x^2)-n^2x^2$ for any $n$?

Comment: Simple and does the job, thanks! You could post it as an answer.

Comment: OK, I will post ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the fucnctions $f(x)=\sin(nx)+n^2x^2$ and $g(x)=n^2x^2$ are convex (as the second derivative is $> 0$) and
$\sin(nx)= f(x)-g(x)$ has arbitrarily many local maxima and minima.